# How do I display a number range when a number is entered?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet of clients and columns for their names, addresses, and ages. I'd like to display an age range in the column when their specific age is entered. For example, if Tina is 32, I'd like the "age" column to show "30-35" instead of 32.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way may be to create a lookup table in which `30-35` is in a cell immediately to the right of `30` (with the next row something like `36` and `36-40`) and then rely on VLOOKUP's inexact matching, where if a value (eg `32`) is not found the next lower is chosen, because of the ascending order of the table. So something like:

```
 =VLOOKUP(32,table,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have the following three columns name, address, age
you could create a fourth column and copy + paste in the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(C1),INT(C1 / 5) * 5 & "-" & INT(C1 / 5) * 5 + 5, "")
```

Once pasting the formula into the new column you can drag-down to extend it for all rows. You can then right click on the header of the age column and select Hide to be left with only the age range.

The above formula assumes column C is the age, and will display the age range only if a number is entered.